# Twinkle immediately terminates when trying to run it in the background

Tags: linux, sip, background-process, raspbian

I am new to Linux and I am trying to use the SIP-client "Twinkle" on a raspberry pi. I can run the program just fine when starting it from the shell just via `twinkle -c`.

This yields:

```
Firewall/NAT discovery in progress.
Please wait.

Twinkle 1.10.1, October 7, 2016
Copyright (C) 2005-2015  Michel de Boer and contributors

Users:
* twinkle
    Schranken <sip:676@###>

Local IP:       255.255.255.255


twinkle: registering phone...

Twinkle>
twinkle: registration succeeded (expires = 360000000 seconds)
```

But when I try to run it in the background, for example with`nohup twinkle -c </dev/null > /home/pi/log 2>&1 &`, the job immediately terminates.

The logfile contains the following:

```
Firewall/NAT discovery in progress.
Please wait.

Twinkle 1.10.1, October 7, 2016
Copyright (C) 2005-2015  Michel de Boer and contributors

Users:
* twinkle
    Schranken <sip:676@###>

Local IP:       255.255.255.255


twinkle: registering phone...

Twinkle>

Info: Deregistering phone...
```

My endgoal is to run it automatically after startup, which I already tried via rc.local, systemd, init.d and crontab, but none of these work.

I hope I provided you with enough information and thank you in advance for your time.

Edit: Using screens solved my problem. I added a command to the rc.local file that opens a screen and the commands for starting twinkle. Thank you!

Comment: Use tmux or screen for that.

Comment: can you give me a example how to use screen or tmux ? but i canot run twice only once ( not in reboot ) becouse some times its crashes and i need to restart

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is such a problem, I solved it using the screen utility.

Install:
`sudo apt install screen -y`

And try:
`screen -D -m -S TwinkleProcName twinkle -c`